# Create trigger for "before insert"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I want to make a trigger for one table that will be used before `INSERT`.

I want to check if two columns are NULL and if they are `NULL` raise an error otherwise `INSERT` the data.

So far I have this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INS_TABLE_1
ON mytable
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    IF (column1 IS NULL OR column2 IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You are not allowed to Add These Data.', 10, 11)
    END
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO mytable (column1,column2,column3)
END
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `BEFORE INSERT` triggers. You can have an `ON INSERT` (which is equivalent to an `AFTER INSERT`), or then you can have a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.

Comment: Why are the fields nullable if you don't want them to be null?

Comment: Yes but i want to raise my own error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [instead trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [inserted table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214435%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) like below and have a try.

```
CREATE TRIGGER INS_TABLE_1
ON mytable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fn varchar(50),@ln varchar(50)
    SELECT @fn=column1 ,@ln=column12 from inserted
    IF (@fn IS NULL OR @ln IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You are not allowed to Add These Data.', 10, 11)
    END
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO mytable (column1 ,column2) values (@fn,@ln)
END
```

The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during `INSERT` and `UPDATE`statements. Instead of trigger replaces the current INSERT by the trigger definition.